# React Native onLayout not triggering at all

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native (v0.58.3), I'm trying to call `onLayout` event on  in a child component to get height and width of dynamically rendering child component. But, the event is never getting triggered. I also tried to apply `onLayout` on parent  itself, but still it does not trigger. I tried with applying hard-coded height to the , still no success. Any help will be appreciated as I am new to React Native.

Parent Component (index.js):

```
render() {
    const {input} = this.state;

    let data = input && !this.state.loader ? <ActionCardListView data={input}/> : this.jlSpinner();
    return (
        <View style={[!this.state.loader && input ? commonContainerCSS.container : commonContainerCSS.loaderContainer]}>
            {data}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Grandchild Component:

```
render = () => (
    <View style={standardSurveyStyles.container}>
        <View style={standardSurveyStyles.card_layout_portrait} onLayout={this._onLayoutEvent}>
            <View style={standardSurveyStyles.imageContainer_layout_portrait}>
                <Image style={{width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height}}
                       source={require('../../../../landscape.png')}/>
            </View>

            <View style={standardSurveyStyles.dataContainer_layout_portrait}>
                <View style={standardSurveyStyles.header}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={standardSurveyStyles.headerText}>Patient satisfaction</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={standardSurveyStyles.descriptionTextContainer}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={standardSurveyStyles.descriptionText}>Ask your patients to tell you about their visit and the quality of their experience with doctors, support staff, and your facilities.</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={standardSurveyStyles.dateContainer}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={standardSurveyStyles.dateText}>About an hour ago</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={standardSurveyStyles.footer}>
                    <View style={standardSurveyStyles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={standardSurveyStyles.startButton}>
                            <Text style={standardSurveyStyles.startButtonText}>START</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: it will fire the first time when the component mount?

Comment: It is not triggering at all for me. Is there any other way to get width and height of dynamically rendered component like we can do on web?

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: I have mediator component which contains a library: https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view and I render children components based on various cases.

Comment: i suggest you to apply onLayout on top most View and see

Comment: I tried `onLayout` on `<View style={standardSurveyStyles.container}>` and even on `<View style={[!this.state.loader && input ? commonContainerCSS.container : commonContainerCSS.loaderContainer]}>
            {data}
        </View>` but no console log is printed.

Comment: okay let me implement this

Comment: i got the data onLayout change method

Comment: Is anything workaround need to add?

Comment: Also have the same problem - React Native Android app